# Seam Hello World won't work through Eclipse

Tags: deployment, jboss, seam

I'm trying to follow any tutorial there is on the Internet to create a Seam "hello world" app.

I've installed Seam 2.2.Final, and deployed some of its tutorials using ant on my JBoss 5.1 server. They work.

Now, I'd like to run any of these (or even an empty project) from Eclipse, and this can't be done.

So, what I'm doing in Eclipse is this:

File -> New -> Seam Web Project

In the Seam Facet configuration, I create a connection profile for my mysql database, using mysql driver I downloaded: mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar

When I test the connection, the ping returns success.

Next I finish the project Wizard and restart my JBoss 5.1 server.

It returns 3 exceptions:

```
        17:51:35,334 ERROR [[/SeamPr2]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener
        com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamApplicationFactory
            at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:213)
            at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:196)
            at org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener.contextInitialized(JBossJSFConfigureListener.java:60)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
            at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
            at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
            at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
            at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
            at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
            at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
            at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
            at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
            at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
            at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
            at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
            at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
            at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
            at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
            at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
        Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamApplicationFactory
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
            at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:537)
            at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:405)
            at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$400(FactoryFinder.java:135)
            at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:717)
            at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:239)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:186)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:131)
            at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:203)
            ... 71 more
```

Here's the second one:

```
        17:51:40,811 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss.web.deployment:war=/SeamPr2 state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
        org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/Users/nataliazon/devel/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/5c4o13-6fo297-h37fm7za-1-h37fmra7-v/SeamPr2.war/ deployment failed
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:331)
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
            at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
            at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
            at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
            at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
            at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
            at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
            at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
            at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
            at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
            at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
            at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
            at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
            at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
            at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
            at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

And the third one:

```
        17:51:40,830 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfsfile:/Users/nataliazon/devel/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/SeamPr2.war/ state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
        org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/Users/nataliazon/devel/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/5c4o13-6fo297-h37fm7za-1-h37fmra7-v/SeamPr2.war/ deployment failed
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:331)
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
            at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
            at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
            at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
            at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
            at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
            at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
            at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
            at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
            at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
            at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
            at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
            at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
            at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
            at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
            at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Please, help me. I have no idea where the errors come from, since ant deployment on the same JBoss5.1 and Seam 2.2 works fine, and I follow the tutorials step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never had good luck creating a Seam project through Eclipse.  It's simpler to use seam-gen to create your project in your eclipse workspace, open Eclipse and create a new project(not a seam project, just a plain project) using the same name as the project you just made in seam-gen.  The project can then be built and configured through eclipse.
Word of advice about using 2.2 and JBoss 5 - you might want to consider Seam 3 or at least the Beta Seam 2.3 with JBoss 7 if you plan on staying with Seam.  Except for a few people(Marek Novotny put together 2.3) Seam 2 is no longer being maintained.  Seam 3 doesn't work with JBoss 5 and Seam 2 requires major contortions to work with JBoss 7.   The transition has been handled poorly and doesn't look like that will improve with The Seam 3 - Apache Delta Spike move.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I have been struggling with Eclipse for 2 days now, and even though some problems have vanished (though for reasons unknown to me), more and more new problems are appearing. It's like a matryoshka doll of endless exceptions. What a painful experience.
I finally gave up and decided to do it through seam-gen, and it works so far.